# facebook profile image without authentication for iOS

Tags: json, facebook, profile

Facebook graph API tells me I can get a profile picture of a user using

http://graph.facebook.com/517267866/picture?type=large

which works fine. However, when you type above URL into a browser, the actual address of the image is

http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/hs232.ash2/49622_517267866_2709_n.jpg

How can I get the second URL using the first link in iphone sdk. ? I mean using objective C.

Thanks and appreciate the help ..!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the original image URL by going to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID?fields=picture
```

See an example in the Graph API Explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dpicture

This doesn't return the large version of the image though. If you want that, you need to make an FQL query on the User table, and ask for the

```
pic_big
```

field.

Comment: For the large version of the image you can use this url : `http://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture?type=large&redirect=false` instead of using FQL. the parameter `redirect=false` will avoid the redirection to the image and send you the JSON data